# Has anyone collated a comprehensive list of all the prototype-programming style javascript work?

Tags: javascript, prototyping

I'm looking for a comprehensive (or as close as possible) list of all the [prototype-programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) style javascript work done to date. Does anyone know of such a list somewhere, or have the knowledge to compile it somewhere and then reference it here?

Comment: What do you need to know for?

Comment: I'm curious - I'd like to geek out different styles/approaches, especially in Javascript, where I can get a rough comparison to functional and class based styles.

Comment: Just wondering: AFAIK, all JS code is prototype-based. Are you using a function? You're using an object that uses the `Function.prototype`, which in turn inherits from the `Object.prototype`. Are you using arrays, `Array.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype`, are you doing as simple as `'string constant'.charCodeAt(0)`, you're creating a temporary instance of `String`, which inherits from `String.prototype`, which in turn inherits from `Object.prototype`. Same goes for `window` and `document`... everything is an object, everything is prototype-based

Comment: @Elias Javascript's "prototype" isn't "prototype-programming" - please read the linked wikipedia article for details ;) in retrospect, maybe i should have said "classless" or "instance-based", to avoid exactly this kind of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that a comprehensive list probably does not exist.

Here is a resource that compares class and prototyped based Javascript, which includes examples of the styles you asked for:

http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/Prototype-Based-Inheritance.cfm

You might want to consider a broader question and the possibly flawed underpinnings of class-based design (particularly for JavaScript): [Why make JavaScript class based?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48301/why-make-javascript-class-based)